# Open or run a VBA macro from Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a VBA macro from Python.

It doesn't give an error but does nothing.

I attached the code. I commented the part of running the macro because I cannot even open an Excel file from Python.

```
import win32com.client as wincl

def runMacro():

    if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\care\\macro_conversion.xlsm"):

        excel_macro = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.application")
        excel_path = os.path.expanduser("C:\\Users\\care\\macro_conversion.xlsm")
        workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
    #excel_macro.Application.Run\
    #   ("ThisWorkbook.Template2G")
    #Save the results in case you have generated data
    # workbook.Save()
    #excel_macro.Application.Quit()  
        del excel_macro

runMacro()
```